# I got this error when I replay my script ( Http Status-code=409 (conflict) ) in LR how to fix it?

Tags: performance, testing, load, loadrunner

Below is the LR Script:

```
    web_add_auto_header("Origin", 
        "http://lbslx-imaljava:8202");

    web_custom_request("j_spring_security_check", 
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/unSecureAction_prelogin", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/unSecureAction_prelogin", 
        "Snapshot=t19.inf", 
        "Mode=HTTP", 
        "Body=PATHPARAM=DBAu%2F1ur8s2Oq%2F1n3TD5tRICutNCSnUYwnGH3rN8QEqhElugryO8jmV1zU6iA4MromyFVFer3DjPX89HsX79iOXHFssJpO2GHYsWh%2BPOwhF7obn9tsnK39K1u5q66YxKnUg55YVOX%2BE3W%2BIzrcPJTYGHr1uiZQDKKAxbEeGGlG%2FWc2ElaxMeky16sxAkwUmDYQY1TlZufypFjeizaFcnXg%3D%3D", 
        LAST);

    web_concurrent_start(NULL);

    web_custom_request("aes.js_2",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/cryptojs/aes.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/path/PreMain.jsp",
        "Snapshot=t22.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("security-util.js_2",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/cryptojs/security-util.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/path/PreMain.jsp",
        "Snapshot=t23.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("pageLoading.gif", 
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/style/images/pageLoading.gif", 
        "Method=GET", 
        "Resource=1", 
        "RecContentType=image/gif", 
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/path/PreMain.jsp", 
        "Snapshot=t27.inf", 
        LAST);

    web_concurrent_end(NULL);

/*Correlation comment - Do not change!  Original value='di4g73sfnqAr5R1H6aLtomD8U1jU%2FBnslz9BKOQG9gAhjTC3VWKVngnUvbYDIrU1LKfQl%2FcXrTIv4Z5E3TSGomrakxSg8NI%2BrzFmqCohIgCDV6qtA2pYQtBHOt1488Q78NnEu1E2TfakFnwGGezj2A%3D%3D' Name ='PATHPARAM' Type ='ResponseBased'*/
    web_reg_save_param_regexp(
        "ParamName=PATHPARAM",
        "RegExp=PATHPARAM=(.*?)\\\r\\\n",
        SEARCH_FILTERS,
        "Scope=Headers",
        "IgnoreRedirections=No",
        "RequestUrl=*/loginCompBrAction_loginCoBrScreen*",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("loginCompBrAction_loginCoBrScreen", 
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_loginCoBrScreen", 
        "Method=POST", 
        "Resource=0", 
        "RecContentType=text/html", 
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/path/PreMain.jsp", 
        "Snapshot=t29.inf", 
        "Mode=HTTP", 
        "Body=PATHPARAM=QVI4XKyMhgXnzd9L1puRZMCaNHpELb5Y%2BQz3o3OX3MPPOtu1N39ODm61DoAmEpC02Yks97bIdtwTklZduY%2BU7l3Pwix86t%2F9FCgLku%2BIH10rNllaXMZp2FxmtuYI1vXsLKm5IXKAn%2BVfmOLHvjhuKPD2nhYLSZ5b1w6NHDoOecUfxMw58pBCybeEoejzI7ehISjnk%2Bnr0lSLIWJbPxvZ6vJV6uS7FWQmyKlS4vbFFWoNPNpecarcJ3nYaAEfmh9rUkYaM3G%2BrNiTiwRgjVmQzDkCjkhy5iq9ATojpMsaufGteEl2tnAXSpvu8tIUzKvFkstE%2FrMK5Ni4KT%2FbE4XIUw%3D%3D", 
        LAST);

    web_concurrent_start(NULL);

    web_custom_request("jquery-1.6.4.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/base/jquery-1.6.4.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t30.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery-ui.css",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/style/themeroller/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=text/css",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t31.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery-ui.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/base/jquery-ui.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t32.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.form.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jquery.form.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t33.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.subscribe.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jquery.subscribe.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t34.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("CommonStyles.css",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/themes/path_jquery_smoothness/CommonStyles.css",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=text/css",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t35.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("pageComponentStyles.css",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/style/pageComponentStyles.css",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=text/css",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t36.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.msgbox.css",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/style/msgbox/jquery.msgbox.css",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=text/css",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t37.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.struts2-3.2.0.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/struts2/jquery.struts2-3.2.0.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t38.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("utils.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/struts/utils.js",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=text/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t39.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("CommonFunc.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/CommonFunc.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t40.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("CommonFuncComponent.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/CommonFuncComponent.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t43.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.numeric.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jquery.numeric.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t44.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.msgbox.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jquery.msgbox.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t45.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.dragndrop.min.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jquery.dragndrop.min.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t46.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jshashtable.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jshashtable.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t47.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("jquery.numberformatter.js",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/jquery/js/plugins/jquery.numberformatter.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=application/javascript",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t48.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("security-util.js_3",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/cryptojs/security-util.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t49.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("aes.js_3",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/cryptojs/aes.js?_={_}",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t50.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("fullscreen_icon.png",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/images/fullscreen_icon.png",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=image/png",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t51.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("down-icon.png",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/images/down-icon.png",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=image/png",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t52.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("home_icon.png",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/images/home_icon.png",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=image/png",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t53.inf",
        LAST);

    web_custom_request("power_icon.png",
        "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/common/images/power_icon.png",
        "Method=GET",
        "Resource=1",
        "RecContentType=image/png",
        "Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/pathdesktop/loginCompBrAction_!loginCompBr.action?PATHPARAM={PATHPARAM}",
        "Snapshot=t54.inf",
        LAST);
```

I recorded a script, when I replay this script it gives me below error.

> (vuser_init.c(29): Error -26622: HTTP Status-Code=409 (Conflict) for "http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/unSecureAction_prelogin" [MsgId: MERR-26622])

How to fix this error?

Thanks

Comment: This is not an error of the product, this is a script error. You will need to understand how the server expects to get this request and fix it.

Comment: How to fix this error?? I tried every thing and still got this error

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! is it possible to include the script into the question?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanMousa it is impossible to know what went wrong without examining your environment. As I said, this is not a product error but an error from the server you are working with.

Comment: @DavidTóth I attached the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Unhandled dynamic data.   Record twice.  Leverage your manual correlation skills to address the dynamic pieces.

You likely have something unique associated with the previous session incorporated into your recording which is no longer valid

Comment: web_custom_request("j_spring_security_check", "URL=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/j_spring_security_check", "Method=POST", "Resource=0", "RecContentType=text/html", 
"Referer=http://lbslx-imaljava:8202/imal_core_portal_cp_mashreq_o12/login/unSecureAction_prelogin", "Snapshot=t49.inf", "Mode=HTTP",   "Body=PATHPARAM=DBAu%2F1ur8s2Oq%2F1n3TD5tRICutNCSnUYwnGH3rN8QEqhElugryO8jmV1zU6iA4MromyFVFer3DjPX89HsX79iOXHFssJpO2GHYsWh%2BPOwhHieRL2VB%2F4bi5S0T9mEPOeZcKnJt%2F469P%2B5lAyzvGOLJ%2Fh%2FKgdOHKi3PyHjJlRMDsCx0CELOaEAd2VoG%2BWg54RbZZ7TdD%2FZ1R1cT9A8jyv2Q%3D%3D", LAST);

Comment: This is the script that Roadrunner stooped on it

Comment: Not sure what you're expecting.   Use the techniques taught in classroom and self paced training to identify the dynamic components and address them.   And, "LoadRunner," not "RoadRunner"   Meep Meep

Comment: record script twice & found that (PATHPARAM) some part of it is same & other part different

1st
PATHPARAM=DBAu%2F1ur8s2Oq%2F1n3TD5tRICutNCSnUYwnGH3rN8QEqhElugryO8jmV1zU6iA4MromyFVFer3DjPX89HsX79iOXHFssJpO2GHYsWh%2BPOwhE9CCh%2FZeHprDIyd7W9lPkqJl%2FpjCT3YlaOs5z%2Fkcz3MbRCHORB%2Blm7psZeViRyOs8hAYlrEFdQLpaTi2pck06abjyd93i8gMTxvwA8o7v5XQ%3D%3.

2nd
PATHPARAM=DBAu%2F1ur8s2Oq%2F1n3TD5tRICutNCSnUYwnGH3rN8QEqhElugryO8jmV1zU6iA4MromyFVFer3DjPX89HsX79iOXHFssJpO2GHYsWh%2BPOwhHdNreruIESuKZDZd0WUHmr%2Fjal%2F0FIsYJmAklwn5naojDvANYd%2BKuQhyTRiufOcM%2FG37SGaniS4HPKq1x3nwYdKbfx%2FDNdzxowtipQR25%2BCg%3D%3

Comment: Is there a way to correlate this or what should I do to correlate it

Comment: There are about five different ways to approach correlation.  Please refer to your training material or the self paced training manuals/material for insight into which way works best for your work model

Answer (score 0):

> Error -26622: HTTP Status-Code=409 (Conflict)

This error generally occurs when you already have an order in the cart and it's not allowing you to place same order again.

So either you have to manage "Delete" existing order functionality in your script or change the product details for new order somewhere in the request payload.

Check/Use manual correlation for **PATHPARAM** parameter